# Mapping array to dictionary using object in array as key

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm using RestKit in my iOS app and I can't seem to get this to work. I have the following JSON array:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "streamable" : true
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "streamable" : true
},
{
    "id" : 3,
    "streamable" : true
}
```

I would like to end up with a dictionary looking like this:

```
{
    "1" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "streamable" : true
    },
    "2" : {
        "id" : 2,
        "streamable" : true
    }
}
```

Where I use the `id` value as the dictionary's key. How would I map this using RestKit?

Comment: show your current code

Comment: I don't have any mapping code for this specific case. I do plenty of other mappings and dynamic mappings, I just can't wrap my head around mapping this properly.

Comment: Not convinced you can do it. RestKit wants to map into a custom object, not to map into an arbitrary dictionary structure.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, you have array of Disctionaries , iterate through the dictionaries and find for the id make this a new Dictionary

For Instance :

```
NSArray *arrDictionaries = // .....

NSDictionary *result =[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

for(NSDictionary *dict in arrDictionaries){
 NSstring *key = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];

 [result setObject:dict forKey:key];
}
```

Note : I've not tested

Comment: I know how to do this in Objective-C, I want to know how I do it using RestKit.